# Intent to start email called from registerForActivityResult(StartActivityForResult() does not complete the activity result on RESULT_OK

Tags: android, startactivityforresult, registerforactivityresult

All the code below is in BackupRestoreActivity.kt

```
class BackupRestoreActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {.....
```

An Intent attaches a copy of a database file to an email. The database file is in a temporary location. After the email is completed the activity result callback should kick off deletion of the database file from its temporary location.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    startEmailActivity = registerForActivityResult(StartActivityForResult()
    ) { result :ActivityResult ->
        if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val file = File(mediaStorageDir, backupFileName)
            file.delete()
        }
    } .......
```

and

```
// Attach backup file to default email
private fun composeEmail(dirPath :File, backupFileName :String) {

    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO).apply {
        data = Uri.parse("mailto:") // only email apps should handle this

        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "")
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Fragments backup attached")
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, ":)")
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://$dirPath/$backupFileName"))
    }

    startEmailActivity.launch(intent)
    return
}
```

The  email gets created in Gmail with the backup file attached. I send the email  BUT when  my app resumes it does not resume at  BackupRestoreActivity (to run the ActivityResult's File.delete(), as shown in the first block of code above.) Instead, my app resumes at its home screen, MainActivity. The file deletion does NOT occur.

I'm using an API 28 emulation in the IDE and have checked the file location with the Device File Explorer. The backup copy file gets created. The email step works fine. Any thoughts on why I'm unsuccessful in using the ActivityResult's File.delete()  would be much appreciated !

Comment: Is the email sent ok with attachment?

Comment: Yes, the email goes out perfectly via the Intent launching gmail. When the mail app comes up the  db file is attached.

Comment: You must finish the backup activity somewhere yourself as this is no normal behaviour.